# set timer between 2 image swipe in ViewPager Android

Tags: android, timer, android-viewpager

Hi i have 20 images in my ViewPager and I need to move an image to another automatically after 3 seconds

how I do this please?

Comment: please elaborate, I didn't understand the question and maybe, show us the code that you currently have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you must use ViewPager, then:

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed( new Runnable() {
            int item_count=0;
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mViewPager.setCurrentItem(item_count);
                if (item_count == max_count) {
                    item_count=0;
                } else {
                item_count++;
                }
                handler.postDelayed(this, 3000);
            }
        } , 3000);
```

But for your purpose it is much better to use a ViewFlipper and just call these two methods on your ViewFlipper object:

```
//How long to wait before flipping to the next view
mFlipper.setFlipInterval(3000);


//Start a timer to cycle through child views 
mFlipper.startFlipping();
```

Enjoy :)